# Subset an array by string element equivalence in Julia

Tags: arrays, subset, julia

I'm trying to subset an array by the value of an element; specifically, a string representing the class of a sample. For example, using an array, `irisData`, which contains Fishers Iris data:

```
...
4.8  3.4  1.6  0.2  "Iris-setosa"   
4.8  3.0  1.4  0.1  "Iris-setosa"   
6.0  3.0  4.8  1.8  "Iris-virginica"
6.9  3.1  5.4  2.1  "Iris-virginica"
6.7  3.1  5.6  2.4  "Iris-virginica"
6.9  3.1  5.1  2.3  "Iris-virginica"
...
```

I would like to perform an operation which returns only those rows in which column 5 is `"Iris-setosa"`. I expected this to be trivially easy, but I can't seem to find an elegant way to do it. Any suggestions?

The equivalent operation in R would be `irisData[species=="Iris-setosa"]`.

Comment: daycaster has provided a fine answer for the case where the data is in a `DataFrame`. If your data is in an `Array{Any, 2}` then you could just use: `x[x[:, 5] .== "Iris-setosa", :]`. Actually `x[sub(x, 1:size(x, 1), 5) .== "Iris-setosa", :]
` would probably be slightly faster, as it will reduce the amount of temporary memory allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing might work:

```
 irisdata = dataset("datasets","iris");
 irisdata[irisdata[:Species] .== "setosa", :]

50x5 DataFrame
| Row | SepalLength | SepalWidth | PetalLength | PetalWidth | Species  |
|-----|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|----------|
| 1   | 5.1         | 3.5        | 1.4         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 2   | 4.9         | 3.0        | 1.4         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 3   | 4.7         | 3.2        | 1.3         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 4   | 4.6         | 3.1        | 1.5         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
```

Comment: Thanks, `.==` was the key. Clever syntax, actually. Forcing you to specify distribution... That's a good idea.